# How to real time control how much of file should be read

Tags: java, android

I have a `Text Class` to read from `File`, Because of long time process I don't want to read from `File` in one moments! and have `ListView` that when scrolls read remains data from `File`. 
How should I do it brothers and sisters?

Best Regards, Minallah Tofiq

```
public class MyText{


    private AssetManager am;
    private InputStream is ;
    private BufferedReader br;
    private String[] text;
    private String Fulltext="";
    private String linetext="";
    public MyText(Context context,String FILE_URL) {
        am = context.getAssets();
        try {
            is = am.open(FILE_URL);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.i("READ", "cannot read from file");
        }
        br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));   
    }
    public void process(){
        try {
            while((linetext=br.readLine())!= null){
                Fulltext+=linetext;
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            Log.i("ERROR", "can't read in process method");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        text=Fulltext.split("\\d+");
    }
    public String[] returnString(){
        return this.text;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to modify this line

```
while((linetext=br.readLine())!= null)
```

with an additional conditional. Such as

```
while((linetext=br.readLine())!= null && (/*your conditional here*/))
```

Comment: I need to stop cursor in there when conditions has occurred , that when I call process method, starts reading where stoped!

Comment: You could keep track of what line you are on, or you could use `RandomAccessFile`